# igraph in R, how to select edges based on incident vertex attributes?

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, edges, subgraph

I am looking for a way to subgraph edges based on a vertex attribute score of at least one of the vertices that are incident on that edge.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is missing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or any example data of any kind. I'm going to take a risk and answer based on what I can guess Is being asked. First, I'll create a sample graph and assign arbitrary "prop" values to each vertex. I'll color them assuming i'm interested in `prop>=3` and plot them.

```
library(igraph)

gg <- graph.atlas(711)
V(gg)$name <- 1:7
V(gg)$prop <- c(1,2,2,3,3,1,1)
V(gg)$color <- ifelse(V(gg)$prop>=3, "orange","yellow")
plot(gg)
```

[image: full graph]

Now, I can find all the edges connected to a vertex with `prop>=3` with

```
E(gg)[inc(V(gg)[prop>=3])]
# Edge sequence:
#            
# [3]  4 -- 3
# [4]  5 -- 4
# [5]  6 -- 5
# [10] 5 -- 3
```

And if I like I can extract those to a sub-graph with

```
g2 <- subgraph.edges(gg, E(gg)[inc(V(gg)[prop>=3])])
plot(g2)
```

[image: sub-graph]

Comment: Thanks MrFlick! This is exactly what I was looking for. I have never used the 'inc' function. Big thanks!

Comment: Sure. Just in the future, try to include a minimal reproducible example. `graph.atlas` or `graph.famous` can be helpful for this.

Comment: Is there a way I can alter the code in such a way that it does not also select the edges on which ALL vertices satisfy `prop>=3`? I want to select the patents on which at least one but not all satisfy `prop>=3'. Do you know a way?

Comment: @Frank-LA That is a bit of a different problem. Comments don't give me much room to explain but `ev<-get.edges(gg, E(gg)); exce<-xor(V(gg)[ev[,1]]$prop>=3, V(gg)[ev[,2]]$prop>=3); subgraph.edges(gg, E(gg)[exce])` should work for this sample. It basically leaves off the 4-5 edges.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. This works great in this example. But in my real data, I have patents with up to 31 inventors. Is there a way that I can set the restrictions: select if at least one meets criteria but don't select if all meet criteria? Maybe I should open a new question?

Comment: Props for introducing me to the `inc` function. The answer helped me to think through and solve my related problem.